# What's the purpose of passing data:{} to a route?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

The [Angular Material Doc](https://material.angular.io) Site passes {} to the [Homepage](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/homepage/homepage.ts) route:

```
  {path: '', component: HomePage, pathMatch: 'full', data: {}}
```

Just curious what the purpose of `data: {}` is?

### Update

After examining this closer I think that they do it so that they don't have to perform a null check using the Elvis operator in their templates.

In other words they don't have to do `data?.property`.

Comment: `The data property in the route is a place to store arbitrary data associated with this specific route. The data property is accessible within each activated route. Use it to store items such as page titles, breadcrumb text, and other read-only, static data` thats what official docs say. So having `data ={}` is pretty much same as not having it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is that `{} != null` which means that you can determine the difference between whether this has been intentionally set to *nothing* (`{}`) or if a dev has forgotten to set the data for the route which would result in it being `null` *(or `undefined`) I would need to check...*

Comment: `null` or `undefined`?